Frobenius norm of rank-constrained matrix product is bounded
Say I have three matrices $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}$ and $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) \leq r$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is unconstrained on rank. I also assume that all of them are bounded in Frobenius norm by some number say $\Vert\mathbf{W}\Vert_F, \Vert\mathbf{A}\Vert_F, \Vert\mathbf{B}\Vert_F \leq \kappa$
I am trying to show that $ \sup \Vert\mathbf{WA} \Vert_F \leq \sup \Vert\mathbf{WB}\Vert_F$ (sup is over the three matrices)
My idea is blend SVD decomposition and the fact that the Frobenius norm of a matrix is the squared singular values and hence LHS would be cropped as only $r$ singular values would contribute to the sum. But I can't make it formal. Do you have any hints on how to proceed?
——— Edit post @whuber comment!
OK. This was question was actually not posed correctly at all sorry. What I am looking is not really to simply show that $ \sup \Vert\mathbf{WA} \Vert_F \leq \sup \Vert\mathbf{WB}\Vert_F$ but rather to find the separating factor based on the ranked (A) vs. full ranked (B) constraint. So basically looking a result like;
$$
\sup \Vert\mathbf{WA} \Vert_F \leq \textrm{some function of} (r, \kappa)
\\ \sup \Vert\mathbf{WB} \Vert_F \leq \textrm{some function of} (m, \kappa)
$$
Happy to get any pointers! Thanks again :)

I must be misreading this, so could you clarify something? It appears we could restate your problem as follows. Let $X=\mathbb R^{p\times m}$ and $Y=\mathbb R^{n\times m},$ limited to matrices of Frobenius norm $\kappa$ or less. Let $f:Y\to\mathbb R$ be given by $$f(A)=\sup{||WA||_F\mid W\in X}.$$ You seem to be asking whether the supremum of $f$ where $A$ ranges over the subset of $Y$ of matrices of rank $r$ or less cannot exceed the supremum of $f$ where $A$ ranges over $Y.$ That's trivially true, so where is my interpretation incorrect?

@whuber Hi! Thanks for your answer, I clarified my question in main text.

I think there will be no separating factor, as the singular values of $WB$ can be arbitrarily small; for example, if $\text{rank}(A) = r-1$ and all the nonzero singular values of $WA$ equal the largest $r-1$ singular values of $WB$, we can make $||WB||_F$ arbitrarily close to $||WA||_F$ by having the smallest singular value of $WB$ approach zero... so the sups would appear to me to be the same.

Consider the case where $p=n$ so $WA$ and $WB$ are square.  Let $WB$ equal the identity matrix, and $WA$ equal the identity matrix with the $[n,n]^{th}$ entry equal to zero.  The Frobenius norm of $WB$ is obviously equal to $\sqrt{n}$, and that of $WA$ to $\sqrt{n-1}$.
Now, let the $[n,n]^{th}$ entry of $WB$, label it $\sigma^2_n$, $\to 0$.  Clearly $\Vert WB\Vert _F = \sqrt{n-1+\sigma^2_n} \to \sqrt{n-1}$.
We can easily extend this to the case of $r < n-1$ and nonsquare matrices; the key is the singular values, not the shape.  Thus, for every $WA$, there is a $WB$ with Frobenius norm arbitrarily close to that of $WA$.
This indicates that, as long as we know nothing but the rank of the two matrices $WA$ and $WB$, we cannot show that the separating factor is greater than zero.
